# ¿Cómo usar una interface en un componente en Angular?

Tags: angular

He creado la siguiente interfaz, la cual quiero usar para tapar una propiedad, que luego cargo con la respuesta de la api de Strava.

**Interface**

```
export interface Athlete {
    state: string;
    code: string;
    scope: string;
    id: number;
    username: string;
    resource_state: number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    bio?: any;
    city: string;
    country: string;
    sex: string;
    premium: boolean;
    summit: boolean;
    created_at: Date;
    updated_at: Date;
    badge_type_id: number;
    weight: number;
    profile_medium: string;
    profile: string;
    friend?: any;
    follower?: any;
}
```

Al intentar usarlo en el componente

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    athlete: Athlete;
    constructor(
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _router: Router,
        private _oauth: OauthService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._route.queryParams.subscribe((params) =>
            this._oauth.refreshToken(params.code).subscribe((resp) => {
                this.athlete = resp.athlete;
            })
        );
    }
}
```

En la línea de `athlete: Athlete;` me arroja el error

> `La propiedad "athlete" no tiene inicializador y no está asignada de forma definitiva en el constructor.`

No entiendo, he consultado mucha documentación y en ninguna leo que necesite tener un constructor, que además creo que en una interfaz no puede haber, sino que debería montar una clase que implementase dicha interfaz; no sé si sería lo correcto para lo que busco, que es tirar los datos de las variables con las que trabajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por si puedo ayudar a alguien, así lo he solucionado yo.

Si veis una solución mas óptima me encantaría que la comentarais.

Vamos al grano, por un lado mantengo la interfaz que ya tenía

```
export interface IAthlete {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    resourceState: number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    bio: null;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    country: string;
    sex: string;
    premium: boolean;
    summit: boolean;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
    badgeTypeID: number;
    weight: number;
    profileMedium: string;
    profile: string;
    friend: null;
    follower: null;
}
```

Por otro he creado una clase, en la que implemento la interfaz y en el constructor inicializo todas las propiedades

```
import { IAthlete } from './athlete.interface';
export class Athlete implements IAthlete {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    resourceState: number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    bio: null;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    country: string;
    sex: string;
    premium: boolean;
    summit: boolean;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
    badgeTypeID: number;
    weight: number;
    profileMedium: string;
    profile: string;
    friend: null;
    follower: null;

    constructor() {
        this.id = 0;
        this.username = '';
        this.resourceState = 0;
        this.firstname = '';
        this.lastname = '';
        this.bio = null;
        this.city = '';
        this.state = '';
        this.country = '';
        this.sex = '';
        this.premium = false;
        this.summit = false;
        this.createdAt = new Date();
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
        this.badgeTypeID = 0;
        this.weight = 0;
        this.profileMedium = '';
        this.profile = '';
        this.friend = null;
        this.follower = null;
    }
}
```

Y así ahora puedo usarlas para tipar y para declarar nuevas propiedades, incluso se puede tipar las respuestas del subscription (como se ve con el Welcome)

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    athlete: Athlete = new Athlete();
    constructor(
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _router: Router,
        private _oauth: OauthService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._route.queryParams.subscribe((params) =>
            this._oauth.refreshToken(params.code).subscribe((resp: Welcome) => {
                
                this.athlete = resp.athlete;
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Eso se debe a que el modo `strict` de typescript está activado. Puedes documentarte acerca del modo `strict` [Aquí](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict)

La configuración está en el archivo `tsconfig.js` del proyecto, similar a esto:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
```

---

Volviendo a tu caso. En lugar de crear una clase que implemente la interfaz puedes agregar un `!` al nombre de la variable, con eso le indicas al compilador que no muestre el error porque le aseguras que esa variable será inicializada, quedando la declaración así:

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    athlete!: Athlete;
```

Comment: Como duda personal, el tema de usar el (!), no podría llevar a la generación de errores en caso de que por ejemplo, la llamada a la API devolviese un nulo?, si no esta claro que nos podemos ahorrar el hacer todas las clases (no me interesa quitar el strict), pero claro siempre y cuando el usar la exclamación no genere problema

Comment: No habría diferencia con respecto a usar la clase. La validación de inicialización que se salta al usar `!` solo existe en tiempo de compilación luego de eso el código transpilado a JS ya no tendrá conocimiento de esas reglas. Si la API devuelve un `null` se va a guardar en la variable `athlete` y va a reemplazar cualquier valor con el que se haya inicializado.

Answer (score 1):

De la documentación de TS 2.7 ([Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html))

> Strict Class Initialization
> TypeScript 2.7 introduces a new flag called --strictPropertyInitialization. This flag performs checks to ensure that each instance property of a class gets initialized in the constructor body, or by a property initializer.

Si quieres mantener el interface en lugar de la clase que veo que has cambiado, te bastaría con inicializarlo tal y como se pide en el constructor, aunque fuera inicializarlo a null si quieres hacer la asignación más tarde sin indicar expresamente la promesa de declararla con el ! (como ya te han indicado).

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Con null la verdad que me seguía dando error, pero con el tema de ! si que vi que se iba, gracias por la info, la verdad que estaba un poco desactualizado con Angular y estoy volviendo a la guerra.